# ArbFloat package in julia

Tags: julia

I can't install the ArbFloats package in julia.
in pkg, I did:
`add ArbFloats`
and I get the following error:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> add ArbFloats
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
   Installed URIParser ──────── v0.4.1
   Installed BinDeps ────────── v0.8.10
   Installed DataStructures ─── v0.17.20
   Installed ReadableNumbers ── v0.2.1
   Installed Compat ─────────── v2.2.1
   Installed SpecialFunctions ─ v0.10.3
   Installed ArbFloats ──────── v0.3.2
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Project.toml`
  [9689d877] + ArbFloats v0.3.2
    Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Manifest.toml`
  [9689d877] + ArbFloats v0.3.2
⌅ [9e28174c] + BinDeps v0.8.10
⌅ [34da2185] ↓ Compat v4.6.1 ⇒ v2.2.1
⌃ [864edb3b] ↓ DataStructures v0.18.13 ⇒ v0.17.20
  [7774933c] + ReadableNumbers v0.2.1
⌅ [276daf66] ↓ SpecialFunctions v2.2.0 ⇒ v0.10.3
  [30578b45] + URIParser v0.4.1
  [8ba89e20] + Distributed
  [1a1011a3] + SharedArrays
        Info Packages marked with ⌃ and ⌅ have new versions available, but those with ⌅ are restricted by compatibility constraints from upgrading. To see why use `status --outdated -m`
    Building ArbFloats → `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/8d8928161cb7a4e3ca263334948c8acaa71392b7/build.log`
ERROR: Error building `ArbFloats`, showing the last 100 of log: 
depbase=`echo libyasm/symrec.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT libyasm/symrec.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o libyasm/symrec.o libyasm/symrec.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
depbase=`echo libyasm/valparam.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT libyasm/valparam.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o libyasm/valparam.o libyasm/valparam.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
```

I have already deleted julia and installed it again, but the error persists. Furthermore, I installed the Nemo package before ArbFloats and it did not give problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ArbFloats.jl repo](https://github.com/JuliaArbTypes/ArbFloats.jl) hasn't had a commit since 2019, but its README suggest using [ArbNumerics.jl](https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/ArbNumerics.jl) instead.